# Git diff but only for changes on another branch

Tags: git

Suppose I have a branch0 in git.

From this branch0 I create a branch1 and start working on it. After a while I committed changes to this branch1. Meanwhile branch0 is being changed.

If I compare the latest version of branch1 against branch0 I will see all the changes between the branches, not only the changes that correlate to the changes in branch1.

For example, if a file was modified in the branch0, but the file was not modified on branch1, the `git diff` will show me the changes to the file. However the file was not modified on branch1. So I would like it to be ignored in the diff.

In a sense, I'd like to do a `git diff` between branch1 and branch0, but only for the files that were modified in branch1.

Is it possible in git? I can imagine doing it in bash, listing all the files and doing a diff on a one-by-one. But wanted to know if there's an easier way in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use compare arbitrary commits for that

> Comparing with arbitrary commits
>
> ```
> $ git diff test            <1>
> $ git diff HEAD -- ./test  <2>
> $ git diff HEAD^ HEAD      <3>
> ```
>
> 1. Instead of using the tip of the current branch, compare with the tip of "test" branch.
> 2. Instead of comparing with the tip of "test" branch, compare with the tip of the current branch, but limit the comparison to the file "test".
> 3. Compare the version before the last commit and the last commit.

From *examples* at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff.

### Example

Suppose you have this git tree

```
1---2 (branch0)
     \
      3 (branch 1)
```

where in commit 3 you have the changes made to branch1, now we apply and commit some changes to branch0

```
1---2---4 (branch0)
     \
      3 (branch 1)
```

If you now do

```
$ git checkout branch1
$ git diff branch0
```

it will show all the changes between these branches, including the changes that were applied in commit 4 like you already stated.
But you only want to view the changes of branch1, which is basically *a diff against the commit that it was branched off of*, so this should do the job

```
$ git checkout branch1
$ git diff 2
```

where 2 is just an example of a commit hash and would actually look more like e542ghe or something similar

Comment: `2` is the common ancestor in your example, but how do you find that outside your example? `git diff branch0...branch1` will do the diff between the tip of branch1 and the common ancestor between branch0 and branch1

Answer (score 8):

> [`git diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) between branch1 and branch0, but only for the files that were modified in branch1.

That's

```
git diff branch0 branch1 -- $(git diff --name-only branch0...branch1)
```

The three-dots form used above to generate the filenames is

> `git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>…]`
>
> changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both . "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of , which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.

Comment: Note the 3 dots (`...`) instead of 2.

Answer (score 3):

`git diff branch0...branch1`

will do what you want (note the 3 dots)

That is, it will show you only the changes made on branch1, since the *common ancestor* commit. The common ancestor commit, is the most recent commit made on both branches.

In the tree below, `git diff branch0...branch1` will show you changes due to commits A, B, C. The common ancestor is E.

```
     A---B---C branch1
     /
D---E---F---G branch0
```